# Connection string to connect two databases on different servers C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to connect to two different databases on different servers. How do I write connection string for the same.

Comment: You need two connectionstrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the same connection string to connect to two different databases in two different servers

You could bypass that restriction connecting to one of the servers and using it as a gateway to connect to the other one, using a feature called 'linked servers', but that connection would be *server side*, you would not be connecting directly with the second server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find these 2 links helpful:

1/ https://forums.asp.net/t/1455116.aspx?How+to+connect+to+a+Remote+Database+

2/ [Connect a C# MVC application to a remote SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772779/connect-a-c-sharp-mvc-application-to-a-remote-sql-server-database)

From what I understand you want to get data from 2 databases. Each is located on another server. My approach would be to create 2 connection strings as Steve mentioned. Then I would get the data from context.

To get the context you might wanna see this:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Good luck!